# Removing documents from CouchDB replicas

Tags: ipad, couchdb, replication

We have a product that uses central CouchDB databases per client replicating to Apps running on user's iPads. Most of the database can replicate normally but we have two categories of document that we want to filter:

1. Documents with an owner - we want to filter the replication to only the current users documents (and documents with no specified owner).
2. Last X documents of some type. For some sorts of documents we only want to leave the last 10 (say) copies on the iPad.

We can set up both rules easily enough using filtered replication - so that the server only presents the subset of documents we want to the iPad for replication. Except... it does not work.

1. If a document has no owner (replicated) and later an owner is specified, it vanishes from the replication stream - but not from the iPad. In fact the version of the document that remains on the iPad still has NO owner and so we cant even hide it in code.
2. When a document becomes the 11th oldest and vanishes from the replication stream, it does not vanish from the iPad. Indeed unless the iPad database is rebuilt all versions of these documents end up there, and no longer replicate which is worse than just replicating them all in the first place.

We did find a hacky workaround - in the case where a document gains a new owner OR becomes older than X, we duplicate it and delete the original. The delete propogates to the iPad and the new document is filtered out of replication. This worked well enough (although it is a bit inefficient). However then we realised the newly copied document had lost all of its revision information and we were relying on the revisions to track changes!

So - does anyone have any other suggestion? What we are looking for is a mechanism to pull a document from the iPad replicas on demand. I am aware we could instruct the iPad to delete the documents locally - but then sooner or later those deletes would leak back to the server and destroy the original?

Answer (score 2):

> ... we were relying on the revisions to track changes

IMHO this is the most interesting point to talk about an alternative solution.

I'm sorry but i have to say you using the CouchDB revision control in the way it that is not recommended. The document revisions are temporary. The best way to track changes of a document is to write a changes log inside or outside the doc.

How would you persist changes outside the doc itself - yes, you would create new docs. **Surprise: you "Hack" is the right solution \o/**

Maybe you shaking your head and your are not happy because you have tried to remove docs from the iPad to make them invisible client-side. That was the starting point of your "Hack", right?

My recommendation is to not combine "visibility" and "existence". Better would be to use your know-how with building view-indexes server-side in the same way client-side with PouchDB. **Let the replication just handle replication - thats hard enough. Use views/filters client- and server-side to solve visibility requirements.**